# $_POST not working? confused?

Tags: php, pdo

At the advice of a member on here, I have abandoned mysql_ functions and looked into PDO.

I thought id make a simple page to start playing, but I guess i'm the simple one at the moment...

Am I missing something here? it is late, but I just cant work out why this is not working.

PHP:

```
<?php

session_start();

include"dbconnect.php";

$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username=?";
$statement = $db->prepare($query);

if ($_POST['submit']){

    if ($_POST['name'] === ""){
        echo "Please enter a name";
    }else{

$user=$_POST['name'];


$statement->execute(array($user));
$fuser = $statement->fetchObject();

}
}

?>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<form method="post" action="">  
<table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>enter username here</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="name" id="name" type="text" maxlength="20" /></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="submit" id="submit" type="button" value="submit" /></td>
    <td><? echo "$fuser->online" ?></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
```

I am connected to the database correctly because if I remove this section:

```
if ($_POST['submit']){

    if ($_POST['name'] === ""){
        echo "Please enter a name";
    }else{

$user=$_POST['name'];
```

and replace `$user=$_POST` with `$user="Mike";`

It displays Mikes details as it should.

Can anyone help please?

EDIT: found the problem immediately after rereading it on here >_<

I have the submit button as type=button when it should be =submit ...

Comment: Is your form's `action` parameter correctly filled out in your working version? In the code you posted here, it doesn't seem to be included.

Comment: Works fine now.. amazing sometimes. I spent 30 minutes looking at that..

Comment: Sometimes it helps formulating the question because one looks with a different angle on the same problem/code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['somename'])
{
//dosomething
}
```

you have to use `isset` which returns `true` or `false`.

Comment: ive switched it around to this now, so 

if isset postname, then execute, if not , then display my "enter a username message"

it works... but, when i leave the field empty, it doe not display my message :(
`
if ($_POST['submit']){
 
 if (isset($_POST['name'])){
  
  $user=$_POST['name'];

$statement->execute(array($user));
$fuser = $statement->fetchObject();
  
 }else{

echo "Please enter a name";
}
}
`

Comment: Also for submit. You have to use isset($_POST [`submit']). And make sure you're to post the name even if its null. You can do that by checking if it's null change it to empty string ''

Answer (score 0):

Looking over the HTML, try this:

```
<tr>
    <td><input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" /></td>
    <td><? echo "$fuser->online" ?></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Then the form will actually submit when you click the button.

//edit
as mandouh said, I also recomment changing `=== ""` to `isset()`